# Preventing default behaviour of 'return' key in HTML5 contenteditable fields

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage, contenteditable

I'm making a basic task list using localStorage & Contenteditable and when I hit enter (in chrome) the browser adds a new line. I want to prevent this default behaviour and submit the task. The jQuery blur removes the focus but only after adding a new line still.
I tried using,

```
return false
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagagtion();
```

But none of them worked, is there anyway to prevent this?

```
$('.taskContent').keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('.task').removeClass('editing');
            $('.task').children('a').fadeTo('medium', 0.5, function() {
                localStorage.setItem('tasksData', tasks.innerHTML);
            });
            $('.taskContent').blur();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want to do is possible, but I would recommend that you not do it even if it is. In a multi-line edit box, users expect 'return' to go to the next line. Submitting will only confuse and annoy them.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your comment from the UX point but im not actually using it on a multi-line edit box. I'm using it on a HTML5 section element so I think it's ok, anyone else agree/disagree, would love to hear your comments from a semantic POV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've run into this problem before, and I think the issue is that the event fires on keydown not keyup for return/enter/tab and other "special function" keys.

Try changing it to

```
$('.taskContent').keydown(function(e){});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with **keyDown** event because by the time of keyUp the character is been inserted.